# Restore automatic bootup of Windows 8 in UEFI

Tags: windows-8, boot, uefi, gpt

My Acer AMD laptop came bundled with Windows 8.0 in UEFI.

The state it's in now is that every boot stops at a prompt, and I have to hit ENTER at this screen to continue:
[image: Unwanted Interactive Boot Pause]

How can I make this continue by itself into Windows, after any startup or reboot later?

Here is an export from EasyBCD 2.2:

```
Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {9dea862c-5cdd-4e70-acc1-f32b344d4795}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume2
path                    \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
description             \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
locale                  en-us
inherit                 {7ea2e1ac-2e61-4728-aaa3-896d9d0a9f0e}
default                 {17113619-9e68-11e3-beed-806e6f6e6963}
resumeobject            {70401bb3-75ca-11e3-a430-e4437d8de957}
displayorder            {70401bb4-75ca-11e3-a430-e4437d8de957}
                        {70401bb6-75ca-11e3-a430-e4437d8de957}
                        {70401ba4-75ca-11e3-a430-e4437d8de957}
toolsdisplayorder       {b2721d73-1db4-4c62-bf78-c548a880142d}
timeout                 11
displaybootmenu         Yes

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {70401bb4-75ca-11e3-a430-e4437d8de957}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows 8
locale                  en-us
inherit                 {6efb52bf-1766-41db-a6b3-0ee5eff72bd7}
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {70401bb3-75ca-11e3-a430-e4437d8de957}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Legacy
detecthal               Yes
bootlog                 Yes
sos                     Yes

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {70401ba4-75ca-11e3-a430-e4437d8de957}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Microsoft Windows 8
locale                  en-US
loadoptions             DDISABLE_INTEGRITY_CHECKS
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \Windows
nx                      OptIn
pae                     Default
quietboot               Yes
bootlog                 Yes
sos                     Yes

Real-mode Boot Sector
---------------------
identifier              {70401ba5-75ca-11e3-a430-e4437d8de957}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \NST\AutoNeoGrub0.mbr
description             NeoSmart Linux

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {70401ba7-75ca-11e3-a430-e4437d8de957}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Microsoft Windows 8 Safe Mode
locale                  en-US
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \Windows
nx                      OptIn
pae                     Default
safeboot                Minimal
quietboot               Yes
safebootalternateshell  Yes
bootlog                 Yes
sos                     Yes
```

Comment: The reason it pauses is because of the `/noexecute`

Comment: You really need to clean up your boot sector.

Comment: Ramhound, you may be right about `/noexecute` (I'm not familiar enough with the Windows boot loader to say), but there is no "boot sector" in an EFI-mode boot.

Comment: @RodSmith - You are of course right.  I simply meant that boot manager is a mess.